# PHP strpos() not acting as expected

Tags: php

I am attempting to clean up my URLS in the database, however I am literally having a brain-fart.  This is PHP 101 level stuff, but I seriously cannot figure out what's wrong with the following snip:

```
<?php

$domain = 'http://www.example.com';

echo "\n\n\e[31mBeginning Domain is: $domain\n";

if (strpos($domain, '//')){
    $domain = explode( '//', $domain)[1];
    echo "\n\e[33mRemoving HTTP\n";
}

echo "\n\n\e[35mAfter first IF domain is: $domain\n";

if (strpos($domain, "www.")){
    echo "\n\e[33mREMOVING WWW\n";
    $domain = explode( "www.", $domain)[1];
}

echo "\n\n\e[35mAfter second IF domain is: $domain\n";

die("\n\n\e[31m$domain\n\n");
```

When run .. I am **expecting** a "clean" `example.com` -- However my output looks like:

```
Beginning Domain is: http://www.example.com

Removing HTTP

After first IF domain is: www.example.com

After second IF domain is: www.example.com

www.example.com
```

Why is `if (strpos($domain, "www.")){` not entering the `if` ?

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos)? It warns about this - position is 0, which is falsey.

Comment: Try `parse_url()` its easier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not debug the code properly? `strpos($domain, "www.")` returns `0` as long as `$domain`  starts with `www`, and that evaluates to `false`.

By **properly** checking whether `strpos($domain, "www.")`  returns **exactly** `false`, you can fix your algorithm

Comment: Crap .. LOL .. Thank you .. falsey vs false .. I'll accept in 6 mins ..